# What is the correct way of importing React Component in non-React build website?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I built a site with Node, Express and want to add a page which is built with React and JSX.

I've installed Babel as npm package and added React as a script like this into index.html:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
```

and Main module

```
<script src="./js/Main.js"></script>
```

My question is how to properly import a Child Component into a Parent Component.

Lets say I want to import './components/Message.js'
into 'Main.js' like this

```
function Main() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
            <Message />
        </div>
    )
}

const renderDiv = document.getElementById('chat-module')
ReactDOM.render(<Main />, renderDiv)
```

to do this I need to import Message.js into Main.js but
`import Message from 'components/Message'`
gives `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` error.

The only solution I have found so far is to add Message.js as a script into index.html and call it from Main.js as window.Message

Is this the only available solution or is there more proper and efficient way to connect these components?

Note: As a reminder Im not using npx create-react-app. This is an existing app built with express.

Comment: Did you try `<script type="module" src="./js/Main.js">`?

Comment: Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

Comment: Im trying to import Message into Main. Where should I try that script src? Both are React Components as scripts

Comment: In your post you stated that you have this: `<script src="./js/Main.js"></script>` in your index.html. Replace it with what I wrote.

Comment: Nice, please accept my answer.

Comment: It just gives <Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'> error but still works

Comment: How can I accept your answer?

Comment: Ok error was from my previous technique. All fine now!

Comment: Well, your whole setup sounds weird tbh. It depends on your usecase but you should actually just transpile your whole module with babel, which you have already installed, before putting it on a website. Use webpack or rollup or parcel for that.

Comment: I've installed babel to work with JSX. I dont know the other tools you mentioned. Once I complete the module Ill look into them. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you try `<script type="module" src="./js/Main.js">`?

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules